# Cannot find JAR files in jbox2d

Tags: eclipse, jar, netbeans-7, jbox2d

This may sound stupid but I cannot for the life of me find the JAR files in the Jbox2d file folder. There is a readme that says:

```
If you've downloaded this an archive, you should find the built java jars in the 
'target' directories of each project.
```

I am not sure what this means, but when browsing through the file folders (why are there always so many empty folders?) from the Netbeans 'add jars' menu, no files are detected.

I also was previously using eclipse and could not get it to work with this IDE either which is why I downloaded netbeans in the first place.

This may see like a newbie question but bare in mind I mostly code in python where I would simply include an 'import' statement and include the source in the file folder.

Please advise,

Thanks

PS if you think this physics engine is junk (which I am beginning to believe) or if you know of a better engine, do tell.

Answer (score 0):

They were not included. Download from another source.

Comment: Do you happen to know of "another source?"